# How to evaluate $\sum \frac{1}{2^{n-r}}\frac{1}{n}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, divergent-series

$$\sum_{n=r+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{n-r}}\frac{1}{n}$$

,where r is a positive integer.

First, I wanna know if this is convergent(I guess so) and WHY.

And if so, how to evaluate it?

Comment: Ratio test could help for the convergence

Comment: Easier yet: Compare to the geometric series. Evaluating will require considering a power series and differentiating it term by term.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
    \sum_{n=r+1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{n-r}}\cdot\frac{1}{n}=2\Phi\left(\frac{1}{2},1,r+1\right)
\end{align*}
where $\Phi$ is Lerch zeta function defined as
\begin{align*}
    \Phi(z,s,\alpha)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{(n+\alpha)^s}
\end{align*}
This series only converges for any real number $\alpha>0$ where $|z|<1$ or $\operatorname*{Re}(s)>1$ and $|z|=1$.

In this problem, using Lerch's integral representation,
\begin{align*}
    \Phi(z,s,\alpha)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}\int_0^\infty\frac{t^{s-1}e^{-\alpha t}}{1-ze^{-t}}dt
\end{align*}
let $z=1/2, \ s=1, \ \alpha=r+1$, then
\begin{align*}
    \Phi(1/2,1,r+1)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(1)}\int_0^\infty \frac{t^{1-1}e^{-(r+1)t}}{1-\frac{1}{2}e^{-t}}dt=\int_0^\infty\frac{2e^{-rt}}{2e^t-1}dt\overset{\triangle}{=}I
\end{align*}
set $u=e^t, \ du=e^tdt=udt$, so we get
\begin{align*}
    I=\int_1^\infty \frac{2}{2u^{r+2}-u^{r+1}}du
\end{align*}
notice that $u^{r+2}<2u^{r+2}-u^{r+1}<2u^{r+2}$ when $u>1, \ r>1$ which implies
\begin{align*}
    \frac{1}{r+1}=\int_{1}^\infty \frac{1}{u^{r+2}}du<I<\int_0^\infty \frac{2}{u^{r+2}}du=\frac{2}{r+1}
\end{align*}

Comment: This is correct but what is its expansion for large $r$ ?

Comment: WOW. Great!. Thanks to you, by using Lerch's integral representation, I think I managed to get $$ \frac{2}{r-1} > \Phi(1/2,1,r+1)>\frac{1}{r-1}$$
is this correct?

Comment: @ David Lee Yes, you are right! See the process above.

Comment: @Always. Thank you. Btw, $dt = \frac{1}{u}du$ , not $dt = udu$.(you seem to do this) So I finally get $\frac{1}{r+1}$. Originally I made a mistake, too. ;). Anyway, I would never know Lerch if it weren't for you. Thanks.

Comment: @David Lee Oh, yes, thanks for pointing out my mistake.